# How to bind MVC data to Plotly

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, plotly

I'm attempting to bind JSON data to a Plotly graph in MVC. Console is empty and the graph isn't displaying at all. I'm open to alternate methods of doing this.

I have an MVC model:

```
public class DataUploadModels
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Empname { get; set; }
    public string Empid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Annualizedbase { get; set; }
    public decimal Annualizedtcc { get; set; }
    public decimal grade { get; set; }
}
```

It has some sample data which I'm returning to a view in JSON:

```
public ActionResult Plotly()
{
    List<DataUploadModels> list = db.DataUploadModels.ToList();
    ViewBag.jsondata = this.Json(list);

    return View();
}
```

And I'm trying to create a simple plot of it in my view:

```
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script>
array = @Json.Encode(ViewBag.jsondata)
xs = [];
for (i = 1, i < 3, i++){
    xs += array.Data[i].Title;
};
ys = [];
for (i = 1, i < 3, i++){
    ys += array.Data[i].Annualizedbase;
};
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
x: xs,
y: ys }], {
margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
```

Plotly is included in the _Layout.cshtml file and was working with hard-coded data.

Comment: What is `x` in `x += array.Data[i].Title;` (you have not declared that anywhere). And `xs` is just an empty array, so there is no data to display (and in anycase, it would need to be `x: xs`,  not `x: [xs]`)

Comment: In any case, this will be a lot easier if you generate the model correctly in the GET method (by creating a model with 2 collection properties for the x and y values and passing that to the view)

Comment: Hi, x and y should have been xs and ys, as I've updated above. I think I need to send all the data to the view and manipulate it in the view because I'm hoping to add a couple of filters later on, which I believe would be easiest in JavaScript.

Comment: Always create a view model to represent what you want in the view (and your current model does not do that without javascript manipulation!) - but if you want to use you current code, then its `for (i = 1, i < 3, i++){ xs.push( array.Data[i].Title); }`

Comment: It should also be `array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.jsondata))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign your `ViewBag` property to a javascript array, use

```
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.jsondata))
```

and then in the `for` loops you need to `.push()` the value into your `xs` and `ys` arrays

```
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.jsondata))
xs = [];
for (i = 1, i < 3, i++){
    xs += array.push(Data[i].Title);
};
ys = [];
for (i = 1, i < 3, i++){
    ys += array.push(Data[i].Annualizedbase);
};
```